# Flight between non-Schengen countries with Schengen connection after exhausting 90/180 limit

Tags: schengen, transit, brazilian-citizens

I'm from Brazil (no visa needed for Schengen) and I'm still within the 90 days wait to be able to enter Schengen again, after spending exactly 90 days there.

Now I have a company trip to Scotland and I'm concerned I'll have problems when I get to France, in CDG.

I know that there's a thing called ATV (airport transfer visa) you can get when you're from a country without automatic short-term Schengen visa. This is not my case - I do have the automatic visa - but the fact there is a different rule for this case gives me the feeling that this is a special situation.

My guess is that it should be fine because I'm just connecting in Schengen between non-Schengen countries and will never leave the airport international area.

So, is it really okay or am I gonna get a fine and/or sent back?

Comment: To clarify, you want to transit through CDG on your way home to Brazil, and your Schengen 90 days has been fully spent. is that right?

Comment: I've edited your title to reflect that you don't actually have an expired visa (which is a different situation than having exhausted your 90/180 limit).  If the new title somehow misrepresents something, please edit again or let me know.

Comment: @GayotFow no, I'm back to Brazil already. it's a new trip.

Comment: @phoog made it a little bit more generic

Comment: Normally, airside transit does not require a visa, but french authorities have had trouble with nationals of some countries "slipping away" from transit, so they have a tendency to intercept them right in the jetway and escort them to a secure area until their departing flight, which may or may not be a very pleasant experience. Complex transfers (involving inter-terminal buses) probably don't help. Of course, we're considering that you are both arriving in and departing from CDG, don't need to stay overnight in CDG...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the purpose of calculating the duration of stay in the Schengen area, you need only consider travel that passes through Schengen border controls.  As you are in transit in CDG, you should not have to pass through border control.  You will want to make sure of this, though, if you have already reached your maximum of 90 days.

An airport transit visa is not necessary, and won't help in any case.